# ggplot line graph for different categories for different times

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, tidyverse

I am trying to create a line graph per hour for data collected every 15 minutes as below:

```
#load necessary libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

DT <- data.frame(periods=c("7:15- 7:30","7:30- 7:45","7:45- 8:00",
                           "8:00-8:15","8:15-8:30","8:30-8:45","8:45-9:00",
                           "9:00-9:15","9:15-9:30","9:30-9:45","9:45-10:00", "10:00-10:15"),
                 Blue=c(2,4,6,4,11,3,4,6,3,3,9, 19),
                 Red=c(4,5,3,4,7,7,7,9,10,3,10, 12 ),
                 Yellow=c(1,0,6,8,1,6,4,5,3,1,3,2),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
DT


The code I tried is as below:

#load necessary libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

#melt data frame into long format
df <- melt(DT ,  id.vars = 'periods', variable.name = 'colors')

#create line plot for each column in data frame
ggplot(df, aes(periods, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = colors))
```

I would like the lines to correspond to different categories or columns with diffrent colors and x axis to correspond to the hour periods . Also I would like to sum up the 4 "15 minute periods" to make an hour.

How would I do it with ggplot or plotly?

Kindly

Comment: HI R noob! Two questions:

Comment: 1. "I would like to sum up the 4 "15 minute periods" to make an hour." <- your data doesn't have any periods from what I can see?

Comment: 2. I ran your code, and it creates something remarkably similar to what you were saying you wanted. What do you want to be different in the one you have in mind?

Comment: @Mark

Pardon me I posted some solution from here that is not working for me

i have edited the code

Comment: okay question 3. why did you post a question if you had code that already works?

Comment: @Mark
I copied my code from the wrong file...just understand

The code i have posted now does not show lines

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but I have to admit it's not my best work. The first step is to prepare the time period data. For that I would extract the starting time from the `periods` column. I would then get the hour value from the resulting `POSIXct`-object and construct an hourly time interval string.

```
df <-
  DT %>% mutate(
    startTime = as.POSIXct(trimws(sub("-.*", "", periods)), format = "%H:%M"),
    hour = as.numeric(format(startTime, format = "%H")),
    interval = paste0(
      str_pad(hour, 2, "left", "0"),
      ":00-",
      str_pad(hour + 1, 2, "left", "0"),
      ":00"
    )
  )
```

```
> df
       periods Blue Red Yellow           startTime hour    interval
1   7:15- 7:30    2   4      1 2023-07-18 07:15:00    7 07:00-08:00
2   7:30- 7:45    4   5      0 2023-07-18 07:30:00    7 07:00-08:00
3   7:45- 8:00    6   3      6 2023-07-18 07:45:00    7 07:00-08:00
4    8:00-8:15    4   4      8 2023-07-18 08:00:00    8 08:00-09:00
5    8:15-8:30   11   7      1 2023-07-18 08:15:00    8 08:00-09:00
6    8:30-8:45    3   7      6 2023-07-18 08:30:00    8 08:00-09:00
7    8:45-9:00    4   7      4 2023-07-18 08:45:00    8 08:00-09:00
8    9:00-9:15    6   9      5 2023-07-18 09:00:00    9 09:00-10:00
9    9:15-9:30    3  10      3 2023-07-18 09:15:00    9 09:00-10:00
10   9:30-9:45    3   3      1 2023-07-18 09:30:00    9 09:00-10:00
11  9:45-10:00    9  10      3 2023-07-18 09:45:00    9 09:00-10:00
12 10:00-10:15   19  12      2 2023-07-18 10:00:00   10 10:00-11:00
```

We can then drop the `startTime`, `hour` and `periods`-columns, and bring the dataframe into long format before grouping by `interval` and name and making the sum of the values

```
df <-
  df %>% select(-c(startTime, hour, periods)) %>% pivot_longer(!interval) %>%
  group_by(interval, name) %>% summarize(valueSum = sum(value))
```

```
> df
# A tibble: 12 × 3
# Groups:   interval [4]
   interval    name   valueSum
   <chr>       <chr>     <dbl>
 1 07:00-08:00 Blue         12
 2 07:00-08:00 Red          12
 3 07:00-08:00 Yellow        7
 4 08:00-09:00 Blue         22
 5 08:00-09:00 Red          25
 6 08:00-09:00 Yellow       19
 7 09:00-10:00 Blue         21
 8 09:00-10:00 Red          32
 9 09:00-10:00 Yellow       12
10 10:00-11:00 Blue         19
11 10:00-11:00 Red          12
12 10:00-11:00 Yellow        2
```

This data can now be plotted. using the interval as the x-axis, you need to specify the `group`-aesthetic for `geom_line()` because we are plotting a line over a discrete axis:

```
ggplot(df, aes(interval, valueSum)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = name, group = name))
```

[image]

EDIT:

You can skip the conversion to a time object and directly get the hour from the periods string:

```
df <-
  DT %>% mutate(
    hour = as.numeric(trimws(sub(":.*", "", periods))),
    interval = paste0(
      str_pad(hour, 2, "left", "0"),
      ":00-",
      str_pad(hour + 1, 2, "left", "0"),
      ":00"
    )
  )

df <-
  df %>% select(-c( hour, periods)) %>% pivot_longer(!interval) %>%
  group_by(interval, name) %>% summarize(valueSum = sum(value))


ggplot(df, aes(interval, valueSum)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = name, group = name))
```

Comment: this is quite cool! not bad at all haha!